# Unable to get BACKSPACE key to register in Processing 3.0.1 Java Mode

Tags: java, keyboard, character, processing, backspace

I have never had a problem like this before and am probably just making a very simple mistake somewhere but I cannot for the life of me get Processing to recognize anything but alphanumeric characters and symbols. Backspace/delete are not registering. I have tried using the key variable and the key code but nothing seems to be working.

Things I've tried:

```
key == BACKSPACE
int(key) == 8
keyCode == DELETE
```

Nothing has worked. They return null when I try to `println(key)`

Here is my code. This is just a snippet, the rest of the program consists of
several other methods and includes a draw() loop. I've narrowed the problem down to this block.

```
void keyTyped() {
  if (key == '`' || key == '~') {
    consoleShow = !consoleShow; //toggle boolean
    command = ""; //clear command string
  } else if (keyCode == DELETE) { //   --NOT WORKING--
    command = command.substring(0, command.length()-1);
  } else if (consoleShow == true && key != CODED) { // "key != CODED" isn't working either. (CAPS-LOCK is recognized as a char)
    command += key; //concatenate character to end of command string
  }
  println(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have a `draw()` loop to keep the program alive and keep the keylisteners active. So just put `void draw() {}` at the beginning of your program and it will work.

If you only want to use the backspace key though you could achieve that with less code:

```
void draw() {}

void keyTyped() {
  if (key == BACKSPACE) println("You typed the key backspace :)");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just a snippet, there is a draw loop and it is looping properly from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
`keyTyped()` is unreliable. When replaced with `keyPressed()` everything worked fine.